# asp.net custom web user control -- button

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Is it possible to create a custom button -- web user control?  I want certain java scripts to trigger when buttons are clicked.  If so, are there any articles out there that explain the basics?

I completely understand that I can load javascript via .js link or dynamically at page load, but I would like to just drop a control on the page without manually adding code to every page on every one of my projects.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck.  What code would you have to add to every page on which you place this control?

Answer (score 0):

There is the IScriptControl interface you can implement. In MSDN are samples for that.
It will take care of aumatic script including from a resource whenever it is shown on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Web User Control to your project by going to the menu item Project | Add New, then selecting Web User Control.  Then just drop a button on it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    onclientclick="alert(&quot;Javascript Here.&quot;)" Text="Button" />
```

You can then use that in your project.  Replace the onclientclick with the javascript you would like to run.